# Нужна ли запятая перед предлогом У?

Tags: запятые

Всего 3 дня, у вас есть уникальная возможность приобрести товар по сниженным ценам.

Comment: Нет, не нужна..

Answer (score 1):

**Всего 3 дня! У вас есть уникальная возможность приобрести товар по сниженным ценам.**

Считаю такое решение самым простым и оптимально соответствующим воображаемому (раз уж нет реального) контексту. Одно из разговорных значений слова "товар" — собирательное; один и тот же товар можно покупать по разным ценам в зависимости от различных условий скидки. В торговле выражение "товар по сниженным ценам" общеупотребимо и встречается в [специализированной] литературе с советских времён, если не раньше.

Answer (score 1):

Может быть: (1) или уникальная возможность, (2) или три дня, в одном предложении их нельзя объединить.

Поэтому выбираем один из вариантов:

1) Только в течение трех дней **у вас есть уникальная возможность** приобрести товар по сниженной цене.

2) **У вас есть всего три дня**, чтобы приобрести товар по уникально выгодной цене.

Answer (score 0):

> Всего 3 дня, у вас есть уникальная возможность приобрести товар по сниженным ценам.

Начнем с того, что *у* не союз, а предлог при местоимении *вы* (у вас). Далее. Запятая не нужна, но вся фраза звучит просторечно. Также спорно сочетание ед. и мн. ч. в выражении "приобрести товар по ценам". Говоря "приобрести товар" имеем в виду какое-то конкретное изделие, а не какое-то множество изделий, значит цена одна. Конечно, можно представить себе оптового покупателя, который покупает "весь товар", где под товаром понимается какой-то набор изделий, но ведь у вас не такой случай, верно? Значит, пишем "приобрести товар по сниженной цене" или "приобрести товары по сниженным ценам".

Варианты исправления:

**У вас есть всего 3 дня, чтобы воспользоваться уникальной возможностью (и) приобрести (данный) товар по сниженной цене (товары по сниженным ценам).**

**Только в ближайшие три дня у вас есть уникальная возможность приобрести (данный) товар по сниженной цене (товары по сниженным ценам).**

**Только в течение (на протяжении) трех дней у вас есть уникальная возможность приобрести (данный) товар по сниженной цене (товары по сниженным ценам).**

Comment: На протяжениИ. Но эта фраза ещё хуже исходной. Та просторечная, а эта канцеряритная.

Comment: У вас, к слову, тоже очепятка)

Comment: @Niemand "В течение" - не канцелярит?

Comment: В течение – нет. А вот на протяжении, да ещё в таком контексте – да.